# Array index automatically being assigned a value in C?

Tags: c

I am writing a game of craps in C and I have several problems.  I think I am using functions and arrays together improperly. It may have to do with the way I am using returned values? I do not think my if and while loops are off, however they may be. Here are my problems, I am a beginner and am at my wits end:

- The value returned by roll becomes equal to field.
- Pass doesn't reward when its if statements are true.
- Place 9 becomes roll and pays out according to the rolled value, not the amount bet. It keeps giving back 18, as in 9 * 2 instead of the 2 * (bet).

Here is my code: 
I've set the place bets to automatically be 1000 so as to run quickly.
(I did not include my header files, they have the prototypes.)

```js
//
//  main.c
//  craps.c
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "place.h"
#include "dice.h"

//DECLARE VARIABLES
int roll, shoot, bank;

//DECLARE VARIABLES
int bank, payout;
int pass, field, location;
int places [10] = {0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int placer, location, amount, craps;

//MAIN FUNCTION CRAPS!
int main() {
    int craps = 1;
    //DEBUG:SET ALL PLACES
   // clear_bets(&places [10]);
//initialize cash
    printf("*****CRAPS****\n");
    printf("You have $%d\n", bank);
    while (craps == 1){
       // clear_bets(&places [10]);
        printf("Would you like to make a Place bet? 1=YES 0=NO \n");
        int i = 0;
        scanf("%d", &i);
        while (i == 1) {
            print_place_bets (&places [10]);
                place_bet (&places [10], location, amount);
                printf("Would you like to make another Place bet? 1=YES 0=NO \n");
                scanf("%d", &i);}
            pass_line(pass);
            printf("Pass %d\n", pass);
            field_bet(field);
            printf("field = %d\n", field);
        //SHOOT DICE
        roll_dice();
        //COMPUTES PLAYOUT
        bank = bank + compute_payout(&places[10], pass, roll, field, bank);
            printf("Now you have $%d\n", bank);
            printf("Would you like to shoot again? 1=YES 0=NO\n");
            scanf("%d", &craps);}
    
    }
```

```css
////place.c
   

#include <stdio.h>
#include "place.h"


//Clears all bets (set places to zero)
void clear_bets(int places []){
#  ifdef DEBUG
    printf("*****Clearing Bets*****\n");
    int i;
        for(i=4;i<11;++i) {
//MOD
            places [i] = 1000;
            if (i!=7){
                printf("Place %d has $%d\n", i, places[i]);
                i = 0;}}}
#endif

//Places the given amount in the given location
void place_bet (int places [], int location, int amount){
            printf("Which Place would you like to bet on? (4-6 8-10)\n");
            scanf("%d", &location);
            printf("How much would you like to bet?\n");
            scanf("%d", &amount);
            places[location] = amount;
            printf("You bet $%d on Place %d\n", places [location], location);}


//Reduces the bet at location by given amount (not to go below zero)
void remove_bet (int places[], int location, int amount){
    int i;
     printf("Would you like to reduce any Place bets? 1=YES 0=NO\n");
     scanf("%d", &i);
     while (i == 1) {
         printf("Which Place bet would you like to reduce? (4-6 8-10)\n");
         scanf("%d", &location);
                printf("The current bet on Place %d: $%d\n", location, places [location]);
                while (places[location] >= 0){
                    printf("How much would you like to reduce the bet?\n");
                    scanf("%d", &amount);
                    places[location] = places[location] - amount;
                        // something?
                        printf("Place bets cannot be negative, try again\n");
                        places[location] = places[location] + amount;}
                printf("The new bet on Place %d: $%d\n", location, places [location]);
                printf("Would you like to reduce a bet on any other Place? 1=YES 0=NO\n");
         scanf("%d", &i);}
 }

//Returns the current bet at the given location
int get_bet(int places[], int location){
    printf("Which Place bet would you like to know?");
    scanf("%d", &location);
    printf("The current bet on Place %d: $%d\n", location, places [location]);
    return places[location];
}

//Prints out all place bets to the screen (using some combinations of printfs
 void print_place_bets(int places[]){
    printf("*****Place Bets*****\n");
     int i;
     for(i=4;i<11;++i) {
         if (i!=7){
             printf("Place %d has $%d\n", i, places[i]);}}}

//FIELD BET
int field_bet(int field){
    int i;
    printf("Make a Field bet? 1=YES 0=NO \n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if (i==1){
        printf("How much are you betting on the Field?\n");
        scanf("%d", &field);
        printf("You have %d on the Field\n", field);}
    else {field = 0;}
    return field;
        }

//PASS LINE
int pass_line(int pass){
    int i=0;
    printf("Bet on the Pass line? 1=YES 0=NO \n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if (i==1){
        printf("How much are you betting on the Pass Line?\n");
        scanf("%d", &pass);
        printf("You bet %d on the pass line\n", pass);}return pass;}

//COMPUTE BET
//Given the rolled value, returns the payout based on current bets
int compute_payout(int places[], int pass, int field, int roll, int bank){
  int payout = 0;

  //PLACES[roll] = roll?  where to look?
    //knows that places[roll] = bet in place.c but not in craps.c
   // print_place_bets(&places [10]);
  //  printf("debug:compute payout %d\n", places[roll]);
  //  printf("debug: %d\n", roll);
// COMPUTE PAYOUT FOR PLACE BET IF THERE IS A BET ON THE PLACE THAT WAS ROLLED:
if (places[roll] != 0){
    //Places 4 & 10 $9:$5 Ratio
    if (roll == 4 || roll == 10){
          payout = (((places[roll])*9)/5);
}
//Places 5 & 9 $2:$1 Ratio
    //WORKS FOR 9
if (roll == 5){
            payout = ((places[roll]*2));
        }
    //PLACE 9 only pays $18 WHY?
else if(roll == 9){
        payout = ((places[roll]*2));
        }
else if (roll == 6){
        payout = ((places[roll])*7)/6;
        }
else if (roll == 8){
      payout = ((places[roll])*7)/6;
        }
    printf("Won bet on Place %d\n", roll);
    printf("You won $%d from Place bets\n", payout);
}

//Field Bet Payout
//if there is a bet on the field, reward.
    //FIELD BETS: 2 3 4 9 10 11 12
    // 2:1 for 2 or 12
    //1:1 for 3 4 9 10 11
   // if (field !=0){}
if (field != 0){
    printf("field = %d\n", field);
        if (roll == 2 || roll == 12){
            payout = payout + 2 * field;}
        else if (roll == 3 || roll == 4 || roll == 9 || roll == 10|| roll == 11){
            payout = payout + field;
            printf("You won on the Field %d\n", payout);}
        else {
            printf("You lost on the Field\n");}
}

    

//PASS LINE PAYOUT
//If there is a bet on the pass line, reward if rolled.
//1:1 for 7 11
while(pass != 0){
    //    printf("PASS LINE!");
    if (roll == 2 || roll == 3|| roll ==12){
        printf("You've crapped out!\n");
        //LOOSE BET
        payout = payout - pass;
            }
    else if (roll == 7 || roll == 11){
        printf("Natural!  Pass line wins!\n");
         printf("You won $%d\n", pass);
        //WRITE REWARD
        payout = payout + pass;
            }
        break;
    }
    roll = 0;
    printf("You had $%d before payout\n", bank);
    return (payout);

}
```

```html
//
//  dice.c
//  driver1
   
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


//DECLARE VARIABLES
int roll, shoot, total;


//DEFINE FUNCTIONS
int roll_dice(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf ("*****Shooting*****\n");
            roll = (rand() % 6 + 1) + (rand() % 6 + 1);
            printf ("Rolled %d\n", roll);
    return 0;}
```

Comment: I didn't check the  rest of the code, but `srand(time(NULL))` has no business being in the dice-roll function. Call it *once*, preferably at the startup of `main()`. Regarding the rest of this, I can sense integer division may bite you in one way or another.

Comment: As noted in the answer below, `&places[10]` isn't correct, and depending on the stack layout may actually lead to overwriting other variables before going off into no mans land.  You're also off by one when you do this" `for(i=4;i<11;++i)`.  Array indices are from 0 to (size-1), so for an array of 10 items the valid indices are 0 to 9.  Given that you can roll from 2 to 12 you'd need 11 spaces to keep track of all possible rolls but to avoid having to subtract 2 from every roll you might just allocate enough space for 13 items and know that 0 and 1 will never be used.

Comment: The array is not for the dice, it is to hold the bets.  In craps there are 6 "places" to place a bet.  They are known to be 4 - 10, inclusive, I made the array 10, and I don't use 0-3.  In that case, would it still be off?

Comment: Yes, because 9 is the highest available index in a 10 item array.  You appear to use roll as an index to the array, so that's where I assume you would have multiple out of bounds issues.  `places[roll]*2` and such.

Comment: Does that not work to reference to a value held by an index?  I want to generate a roll, and use that roll value to call a value for the index that holds the bet.

Comment: I don't really understand what you wrote.  If `roll == 12` then `places[roll]` is the same as saying `places[12]` which is an invalid index for a 10 element array.

Answer (score 1):

Lines like this one:

```
place_bet (&places [10], location, amount);
```

are passing in the address of the 11th element of `places`, which is past the end of the array. The `place_bet` function then uses this address as the starting point of its `places` parameter, which means it will write even further past the end of the array. Writing past the end of the `places` array is undefined behavior and may cause the value of other variables to change as their memory is overwritten.

To fix this, change the function calls (not the definitions or declarations) to pass the array, rather than the address of an element past the end of the array:

```
place_bet (places, location, amount);
```